# what does this code mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, function-pointers

today I was reading dwm source code where I encountered this piece of code:

```
static void (*handler[LASTEvent]) (XEvent *) = {
  [ButtonPress] = buttonpress,
  [ClientMessage] = clientmessage,
  [ConfigureRequest] = configurerequest,
  [ConfigureNotify] = configurenotify,
  [DestroyNotify] = destroynotify,
  [EnterNotify] = enternotify,
  [Expose] = expose,
  [FocusIn] = focusin,
  [KeyPress] = keypress,
  [KeyRelease] = keypress,
  [MappingNotify] = mappingnotify,
  [MapRequest] = maprequest,
  [MotionNotify] = motionnotify,
  [PropertyNotify] = propertynotify,
  [UnmapNotify] = unmapnotify
};
```

this is a function pointer array, I get it. but why is it initialized this way? I mean what are all those bracket values inside initialization block? e.g. ([ButtonPress] = buttonpress)

Comment: Are they enums or const ints?

Comment: This doesn't look like C code.

Comment: It's just C99 designated initialisers - the values inside the square brackets are array indices.

Comment: @PaulR, thanks, that's the answer. but what is it good for?

Comment: @sepisoad: see the linked answer - it's useful when you only want to initialise particular elements of an array (sparse initialisation) or when you want to decouple the ordering of the elements in the array from the order in which you specify them (for readability, perhaps, or because the order might change later).